# How to use array fill in javascript showing the text or number inputed by the user?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, getelementbyid

So one of my assignments is about that I should let the user type whatever he wants and then I have to fill the array with the input from the user, so it's basically could be number/s or text. I don't know if I should use getelementbyid.value or something else.

SO here´s what I have so far:

```js
Fill1();

function Fill1() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("smth").value;
}

function prfunc() {
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Fill1.fill(text1);
}
```

```html
Type whatever you want: <input type="smth" id="smth"><br>
<button onclick="Fill1()">Fyll</button><br>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: `smth` should be `smth.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rando aside - I believe array.fill doesn't work in IE11, if you have any requirements around browser support.  Dunno about any other browsers, just ran into that last week on a project.

Who uses IE11 nowadays?  Apparently a few thousand of our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let array = Array(10);

function Fill1() {
    array.fill(smth.value)
    prfunc();
}

function prfunc() {
    answer.innerText = array;
}
```

```html
Type whatever you want: <input type="smth" id="smth"><br>
<button onclick="Fill1()">Fill</button><br>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, not the way I want it to be soived

Comment: @Dimarco can you describe what is the way you want it to be solved?

Comment: @Dimarco in code in your question you call only `Fill1()` - how do you want to call `prfunc()` ? There are many ways of doing this - you also use strange notation in that second function `... = Fill1.fill(text1);` what do you mean by this?

Comment: In the assignment I am supposed to use two functions: one for filling the array with the input and the other one for printing the array on the screen..

Comment: @Dimarco I update answer - now we have 2 functions - it is ok? (previous simpler version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58106840/1))